# how show 'no results" in jquery autocomplete, properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to accomplish to implement a message when user search a query that it is not in the list to show **No Search Found**. I tried using

```
$('#searchTextField').html(" NO SEARCH FOUND");
```

but it is not working. Does anyone know how to solve this with my code below? Thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
  var myData = [];
   myData.push("NO SEARCH FOUND");
  $.get("http://localhost:8080/myApp/JobSearchItem.xhtml", function (data) {
    $("#searchTextField").autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      source: myData,
    }).val('NO SEARCH FOUND').data('autocomplete')._trigger('select');


    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
      myData.push({
        id: v.id,
        label: v.label,
        value: v.id
      });
    });
  });
});
```

html

```
     <form id="searchForm" >

          <input type="text" name="searchValue" id="searchTextField" class="form-control" 
                           placeholder="search"/>

      <button type="submit"   class="btn btn-primary" >Search</button>   




            </form>
```

Comment: If `searchTextField` is `input` then it should be `$('#searchTextField').val(" NO SEARCH FOUND");`

Comment: If I put the code the same place I have in my code above - it will just show as a value not in the autocomplete dropdown - when no search is there.

Comment: try `myData.push({id: 0,label: "No results found"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you are looking for if no match found it should be shown in dropdown. so you need to update your code something like this.

```
$(function() {
    $("#userInput").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users", // update with your url
                data: {
                    site: 'stackoverflow',
                    inname: request.term
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp'
            }).done(function(data) {
                if (data.items) {
                    response($.map(data.items, function(item) {
                        console.log(item);
                        return item.display_name + " " + item.location; // return your value which is coming from ajax response
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (!ui.content.length) {
                var message = { value:"",label:"No results found" };
                ui.content.push(message);
            }
        }
    });
});

<label for="userInput">Search StackOverflow user:</label>
<input id="userInput" type="text" />
```

Please check with working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/25f3cz48/7/)

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. :-)